# Finding conjugate harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis

Let's say that u=$e^{sin\left(x+2y\right)\cdot cosh\left(y-2x\right)}\cdot cos\left(cos\left(x\right)\cdot sinh\left(2y\right)\right)$

I need to find v which a conjugate harmonic of u. I am not sure but I suppose that U is harmonic.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried the Cauchy-Riemann's conditions?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz yes I tried...